# Implement binary using counting semaphore

Tags: operating-system, semaphore

I know that a counting semaphore can be implemented using a binary semaphore.

Is vice versa also true?

Comment: How come you can implement a counting semaphore with a binary one? A counting semaphore needs to be capable of storing n different states while a binary one is only required to display 2 states, which isn't sufficient for a counting semaphore.